# TypeScript Generic type intersection does not satisfy itself

Tags: typescript, mongoose, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a problem with generic types. its simplified version is as this.

```
import { Document, Model } from 'mongoose';

interface Base {
  age: number;
}

class Test<T extends Base> {
  private t: Model<T & Document>
}
```

i get an error for this part `Model<T & Document>` which says this:

```
Type 'T & Document<any, {}>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document<any, {}>'
```

Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because the type of `Document` is **class Document<...>**, that is why you can't use intersecion type `&` with the "Object" type directly.

To solve this issue, you could use `extends` to extend the class like following:

```js
class Base extends Document {
  age?: number;
}

class Test<T extends Base> {
  private t?: Model<T>;
}
```

Comment: beautifully correct! i didn't see what you said no matter how much i searched. it made me refactor some of my code but now it makes more sense. thanks